# TypeScript: void return type converted to any type?

Tags: typescript

I seem to be not able to comprehend why the following code does not raise error:

```
var rg: {(): void;}[] = [];
rg.push(function():string {return "";})
```

I clearly state that the type should be an array of functions that return `void`, however I push there a function that returns a `string` and yet the compiler does not complain. If I change the definition of `rg` to

```
var rg: {():number;}[] = [];
```

The compiler starts to complain.

Is this a bug or is it how the void return type is supposed to work (i.e. anything goes if `void` is used, basically making it the same as return type `any`)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is by design (I'll explain why it's good design shortly). The spec says (in section 3.6.3, abridged for clarity):

> A type S is assignable to a type T, and T is assignable from S, if one of the following is true...
>
> - S and T are object types and, for each member M in T, one of the following is true:
>
>   - M is a call, construct or index signature and S contains a call, construct or index signature N where
>
>     - the result type of M is Void, or the result type of N is assignable to that of M.

In this case, we're testing if `() => string` is assignable to `() => void`. So either `string` has to be assignable to `void` (it isn't), or `void` has to be `void` (it is).

---

In effect, the rule here is **you are allowed to throw away the return value**, which is consistent with how e.g. C++ treats `void` in template resolution.

```
function decrementWidgetHeight(w: Widget): number {
    // ... returns the new height of the widget
}

function applyToManyWidgets(w: Widget[], change: (x: Widget) => void): void {
    // for each widget in the array, apply 'change' to it
}

// Later...
applyToManyWidgets(widgetsToShorten, decrementWidgetHeight); // Should be allowed?
```

When we constrain the type of `change` to be `(widget) => void`, we're making it so that you can pass `decrementWidgetHeight` as the second argument even though it has a return value, *but* still making sure that when we write the body of `applyToManyWidgets`, we don't accidentally use the return value of `change` anywhere.

Note that `void` is still different than `any` because this is unallowed:

```
function f() { }
var x = f(); // Disallowed, f() is of type 'void'
```

Comment: +1 - you can test this using: `var rg: {(): void;}[] = []; rg.push(function():string {return "";}) var x = rg[0]();` in the TypeScript playground to see the behaviour in action. Change `void` to `string` and it will allow the return value to be used.

Comment: Okay it makes sense, but is a little counter intuitive, i.e. allowing to add a function that does not match the type, even if it is void in the definition.

Comment: The spec also says "void is only related to the types Undefined, Null and Any", so I'm not sure the spec is consistent. Definitely unexpected.

Comment: as of version 1.4.1.0 as I can see it is allowed to assign void functions calls

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ryan! I do have a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63400854/void-return-type-not-checked-in-typescript-prevent-floating-promises) though, since this behavior creates trouble when dealing with promises.

Comment: What did you mean by "how e.g. C++ treats void in template resolution"?