# Typescript interface with void method - not reporting error

Tags: typescript

why does the compiler not complain about the below code? the interface has one method which is a void. The class implements the interface but the signature is not the same, but still the compiler does NOT complain;

```
interface myinterface {
  getMethod() : void;
}

class myclass implements myinterface {               
  getMethod()  {
    return "return string";
  }
}

var myObj = new myclass()

var strVar = myObj.getMethod();
```

Comment: Code located here in playground http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20myinterface%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20getMethod()%20%3A%20void%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20myclass%20implements%20myinterface%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20getMethod()%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22return%20string%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20t%20%3D%20new%20myclass()%0A%0Avar%20y%20%3D%20t.getMethod()%3B%0A%0A%0A%0A

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761607/

Answer (score 0):

> why does the compiler not complain

The way that I think about types in TypeScript is that the types are the minimal information to satisfy an interface. So as long as it covers the minimum typing then it is ok with it.

So in your example above you have implemented a function with that name that takes in no parameters and did at least an implementation that returns nothing.

As for being able to assign it to another variable outside... if you return nothing from that function then the return of that function is simply `undefined`

The reason why thinking of the typing in TypeScript as minimal to fulfill the contract is because the type checking is 100% optional.