# working function even if it is returning the wrong type

Tags: typescript

I'm doing my first test with Typescript using Codepen.io, and I'm not understanding why, after declaring the function signature and return type using an interface, I can then return a different type without getting any error.

Am I missing something?

**Example code:**

```
interface IPerson {
    getFullName: () => void;
}

class Person implements IPerson{

constructor(
    public name: string,
    public surname: string
){}

getFullName() {
    return this.name + ' ' + this.surname;
}

}


let p = new Person('John','Doe');

console.log(p.getFullName());
```

**Result:**

```
John Doe
```

**Problem:**
Why is logging out 'John Doe' (*a string*) even if I declared a *void* return type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript will throw a compile error, something like this:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'void'.

However Typescript will still compile to Javascript. JS itself doesn't have any sort of notion of types and therefore will just log the value, because the runtime has no clue about what return type `getFullName()` has.

If you don't it to compile when there's a compiler error, you can set the `noEmitOnError` flag in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: so do you think it's just a sort of codepen's bug as it just compiles down to JS? I would get an error if I try to run the code with the code using Typescript compiler, is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, you'd get an error, but ts will still emit the JS files.

Comment: You can try the same code on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ It should definitely throw an error.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried running the code using typescript play and like you said it compiles even if it's alerting me that there's an error. Then I tried using adding an interface and I'm still able to get it work without any errors even if it's still returning a wrong type. Do you know why? Does the interface only checks if the function is present without checking types? I'm editing my original post to let you see the new code.

Comment: It does check types in general, but `void` seems to be the exception here.

Comment: Check out this Q&A, why this was implemented this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761607/typescript-void-return-type-converted-to-any-type

Comment: Thank you that was exactly the information I was looking for

Comment: Absolutely no problem!  :)