# Use Observable<void> or Observable<any> to emit `null` value?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactivex

There are cases where the return value of an async operation is not important or not given at all. In those cases, method signatures of async operations often define `Observable<any>` or `Promise<any>` as return value.

#### Example

For example the [Ionic2 NavController](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/c337f0abed78ab8e6fa2f4b5db46f58b6cac74a6/src/navigation/nav-controller.ts#L407-L415) defines:

```
/** // ...
 * @returns {Promise} Returns a promise which is resolved when the transition has completed.
 */
 abstract remove(/* ... */): Promise<any>;
```

Without looking at the actual implementation I cannot tell whether there really is no value emitted (e.g. `null` or `undefined`) or whether I could extract some useful information from the emitted values.

#### Question: `Observable<void>`?

I haven't seen `Observable<void>` or `Promise<void>` in the wild. By using that it would be clear that there is no useful value being emitted. Are there any *technical reasons* not to use the `void` type with observables? Or why is no one using that to designate empty values?

Comment: I think the reason is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761607/typescript-void-return-type-converted-to-any-type

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any technical reasons not to use the void type with observables? Or why is no one using that to designate empty values

There is no hazard in using `Promise<void>` as far as I am aware.

Comment: Promises and Observables are not the same thing.