# Restriction of Function Signature does not work as expected

Tags: typescript

As far as I understand Typescript, the type restriction I provide here on the interface should restrict the declaration of a function of type 'funcInterface' to functions that take a numerical parameter and return nothing. Still, it is possible to assign a funtion with no parameter that returns a string. Why?

```
interface funcInterface {
    (s : number): void
}

var func1: funcInterface = function (s : number) {
    return;
}

var func2: funcInterface = function () {
    return 'abc';
}
```

Comment: TypeScript is structurally typed, that's why you can leave out the arguments in the implementation. For the return type see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761607/typescript-void-return-type-converted-to-any-type).

Comment: These questions are answered in the TypeScript FAQ: [fewer params](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters), [more return values](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void)