# Input restrict characters in ant design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I have ant design form with inputs and i need to restrict some character to be written in input.

```
<Form.Item
              {...formItemLayout}
              label={this.props.intl.formatMessage({ id: 'customer.form.zipCode' })}
            >
              {getFieldDecorator('zip_code', {
                validateTrigger: 'onBlur',
                initialValue: this.props.addressFormDefaults ? this.props.addressFormDefaults.zip_code : '',
                rules: [
                  {
                    transform: (value) => typeof value === 'string' ? value.trim() : undefined,
                    required: true, message: this.props.intl.formatMessage({ id: 'validation.requiredField' }),
                  },
                ],
              })(
                <Input
                  type="number"
                  size="large"
                  className={this.props.useSmartForm ? `${this.props.smartFormClassInstance} ${SMARTFORM_CLASS.ZIP}` : undefined}
                  form={this.props.formId}
                  disabled={this.props.formDisabled}
                />,
              )}
            </Form.Item>
```

so ideal solution would be add some of the key press events and validate it like

```
<Input
  type="number"
  onKeyDown={(event) => {
    // some validation;
    if (someValidation()) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }}
/>;
```

but from the ts definition

```
onKeyPress?: KeyboardEventHandler<T>;
type React.KeyboardEventHandler<T = Element> = (event: KeyboardEvent<T>) => void
```

its void function. when i try to return false it wont restrict. ant design is somehow retarded and dont return value from this callback.
the user should not be allowed even to write it.

alslo i dont use any state, only initial value for event.

is there solution how to add classic onKeyPress, onKeyDown etc. input events, not ant design events?

thx

Comment: Why using onKeyDown? you can control the state `onChange`

Comment: the same way i can control state in onKeyDown, onKeyPress doesnt matter. the point is why would i even change state. its just compicate things when there is already easy html5 solution for this

Comment: did you find any solution to this? I am still looking for one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I implemented something similar on Antd inputs just the other day with a general function from another answer.  This works as expected, just write a regex for whatever characters you want to allow, using `React.KeyboardEvent` as the parameter:

```
const onKeyPress = (e: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
   const specialCharRegex = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9@.' ,-]");
   const pressedKey = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
   if (!specialCharRegex.test(pressedKey)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
   }
}
```

**UPDATE:** What version of AntD are you using and where are you seeing that defnition? I'm using 3.23.1, and the `InputProps` interface has no explicit definition for `onKeyPress`.  However the Input component forwards all additional props to the basic HTML input it's rendering in its return statement, so there shouldn't be any type conflicts.

Generally, event handlers do not return explicit values, but are by [default true](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/returnValue), and can return `false` to indicate the event has been cancelled, as the function above does.  As to why a function with a return type of void would allow a return of false, it's a deliberate exception made by TypeScript, which is explained in-depth by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761607/typescript-void-return-type-converted-to-any-type).

Comment: My pleasure.  I updated my answer if you're still having issues, there shouldn't be any required props of type ```KeyboardEventHandler``` on the Input component, at least not in any recent AntD versions.

Comment: yes this definition si not from antd. but implementation is. in this case they should in input onKeyDown event return value from event not just call the event.

Comment: <input type="text" onKeyDown="return props.onKeyDown()" /> or somthing like this. problem is that this input does not return

Comment: Generally, keyboard event handlers do not return values.  False is an exception to indicate the event has been cancelled.  You can read about it in the [event documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/returnValue)

Answer (score 0):

In addition, I am just using regex format with antd design.

```
<Form.Item>
    {getFieldDecorator('mobile', {
        rules: [
            {
                required: true,
                pattern: new RegExp("^[0-9]*$"),
                message: "Wrong format!"
            },
        ],
    })(
        <Input
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Phone number"
        />,
    )}
</Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simply use from normalized prop of FormItem like this example**

```js
const normalizeValue = (value) => {
    // Just replace the following regex to what you wnat
    const filteredValue = value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/g, '');
    return filteredValue;
   };


<FormItem label="Input" normalize={normalizeValue}>
   <Input
     name="input"
   />
</FormItem>
```