# Typescript: Checking type of function passed as an argument

Tags: angular, typescript, types, interface, rxjs

So, I have the following idea: I would like to describe a function which takes an RxJs Observable provided by some service as a first argument and OnNext function handler which will be passed to subscribe method.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export interface OnNextHandler<T> {
  (value: T): void
}

export interface ServiceSubscriber<T> {
  (providedObservable: Observable<T>, onNext: OnNextHandler<T>): void
}
```

The code above seem to work, though TS doesn't give me an error in some cases(and I would like it to do so).
For instance:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-notes-list',
  templateUrl: './notes-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notes-list.component.scss']
})
export class NotesListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  activeNotes: Note[] = [];
  archivedNotes: Note[] = [];

  private destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(
    private notesService: NotesService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const { active, archived } = this.notesService; // pull our observables from the service
    this.subscribeTo(active, activeNotes => this.activeNotes = activeNotes);
    this.subscribeTo(archived, archivedNotes => this.archivedNotes = archivedNotes);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
  }

  private subscribeTo: ServiceSubscriber<Note[]> = (providedObservable$, onNext) => {
    providedObservable$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(onNext)
  }
}
```

This is one of the Angular components where I'm trying to type the `subscribeTo` method with my `ServiceSubscriber` interface. The first argument gets checked: for example when we pass string instead of an expected `Observable`, but the second argument(onNext callback) can receive any function as its value(and I want it to be a function which takes argument of type `T` and return **nothing**).
To demonstrate, if I change the code inside `ngOnInit` to something like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const { active, archived } = this.notesService;
    this.subscribeTo(active, activeNotes => activeNotes); // pay attention here on the 2nd arg
    this.subscribeTo(archived, archivedNotes => archivedNotes); // and here as well
  }
```

So now callbacks return something, instead of nothing as it was expected. What do I miss here and how can I receive an error when the callback function signature is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: can you please create a stackblitz and share it here

Answer (score 0):

You should type the return as `never` instead:

```
export interface ServiceSubscriber<T> {
  (providedObservable: Observable<T>, onNext: OnNextHandler<T>): never
}
```

I believe this should work.

Answer (score -1):

There is an explanation for this in a different answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761607/typescript-void-return-type-converted-to-any-type).

The short answer is that the spec takes void to be

> "don't care about the return type"

rather than

> "strictly returns no value"