# How to type to prevent a return value in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How do I prevent a user from returning anything from a function in Typescript?

As you can see in [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-t05gv), neither of these types will suffice:

```
type VoidReturner = () => void;
type UndefReturner = () => undefined;
type NeverReturner = () => never;
```

- `void` only tells the user that return value is not important (ignoring the type?)
- `undefined` requires the developer to explicitly return `undefined`
- `never` was a guess, and `void` (as in example 1 returning `{}`) does not match it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: void return type converted to any type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761607/typescript-void-return-type-converted-to-any-type)

Comment: Please edit the question to include your code directly, not as a link. By the way, all three of your functions have type errors when the annotation is `: NeverReturner`, as expected - is that not what you want? [Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAchBuEBOAlCwCuSB2yoF4oAKASgID4pdEkBuAKHoGMB7bAZ2CgEMBmALlgJkaTDjyFSFKAG8Avg1YcuAIwFCaorLiQFiZfJQzYAJhABmAS1wnFbTlCbq4m9Non7pvBkA)

Comment: This is a very legit question and I need the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. It's a [design decision](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void).

A function returning *something* is assignable to a function returning `void`.

Comment: You certainly can: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64688858/388994

Answer (score 6):

You want () => void | undefined

Unfortunately it's possible to cheat with non anonymous functions by first assigning it to another type but otherwise it works when a user returns a value (implicitly or explicitly)

Comment: This actually answers the question and seems to be the only way of enforcing no return type. Very useful for preventing async functions to be unintentionally passed to onClick handlers in React and causing unhandled exceptions in the run time.

Answer (score 3):

Typescript can help you restrict what type you can return. The specific things you can return are:

**void:**

1. nothing (no return statement)
2. undefined (note that just calling `return;` returns `undefined`)
3. null (if --strictNullChecks are disabled)

**undefined:**

You can only return `undefined`! Again, just having `return;` means returning `undefined`.

This also means all code paths MUST have a return statement. You cannot have a code path without one.

**never:**

`never` is a bit special. If a function has a return type of `never` it must never return. That can only happen if *every* code path in the function either:

1. throws an error
2. or has an infinite loop.

I feel you want to prohibit early termination of a function, but that is not possible.

Comment: You're not answering the question. I think the answer is "no, it's not possible".

I had the use case just now: one of my users returned a value in a function with a void return type, it compiles so he thought that return value would be picked up but it does nothing.

Comment: @AlexG I'm not sure what you mean exactly. I think the void section in my answer covers all return types for a function that has void return type. Is there a type I have not covered that your "user" returned?

Comment: I think @AlexG means :
```
type VoidFn = () => void;

const fn: VoidFn = () => 1; // should not be compiled but actually does
```