# 'void' return type not checked in TypeScript – prevent floating promises?

Tags: typescript, promise, eslint, void

Running in TypeScript 3.9.7, this does not concern the compiler:

```
const someFn: () => void = () => 123;
```

I discovered [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12763878/2072165), which explains that this is by design. I somewhat get the reasoning behind it (basically, you should be able to ignore the return type when passing the function as an argument).

But the story becomes a different one looking at promises:

```
const someFn: () => void = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(Error('onoez')));
someFn();
```

I am checking my code with `eslint`s `@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises` rule to avoid unhandled promise rejections. In the script above, since the linter thinks `someFn` does not return anything, it will not warn me.

Is this something I have to live with? If a function accepts a `() => void` type callback, and I pass it an async function, the compiler will not warn me and bad things will start to happen. Can I somehow avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

A return type of `void` means typescript won't let you use the return value, whatever it is. But as you note, that doesn't prevent from returning something. You won't be changing that behaviour.

`() => void` means you don't care what the return value is, because you don't plan to use it. But, in this case you do care.

So you *can* declare a function type that enforces that it does not return *any* value by using a return type of `undefined`.

```
const someFn: () => undefined = () =>
  // Type 'Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(Error('onoez')));
```

Comment: The answer seems very reasonable but I can't figure out why does `function a(): void { return 2;}` cause a compilation error then?

Comment: Because function signatures [works slightly differently](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECEEMBMCgDMCuA7AxgFwJYHtmkgBQCUAXKAG7abSgDeoATgKbqIN4BMA3KAL6ywQoAOLZscVLgDO6UACMyxUAF4AfBSo1loJWtAcgA) than assigning a function to a function typed variable. The idea is that if say a function returns `void` as part of a function _statement_ then the return value could _never be used_, so it enforces no return value. However, if it is an assignment, that function being assigned could potentially be used elsewhere in a context that does allow the use of the return value.

Comment: I see.. here's a snippet that explains what you just sad using code  `const a = {  fun(): void {} }; a.fun = () => 2;` When defining an object literal or a function, you must make it match the signature, but when assigning to an existing typed variable/property, the rules are looser.