# Why typescript compiler allows this?

Tags: typescript, function, interface

I'm wondering why typescript compiler does not complain about this functional interfaces implementations while the signature is different?

```
type GetUser = (userIs: string) => void
interface GetUserFn {
  (userIs: string): void
}

let getUser: GetUser = function (): number {return 1}
let getUserFn: GetUserFn = function (): number {return 1}
```

Comment: See [the TS FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void)

Comment: Found it here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761607/typescript-void-return-type-converted-to-any-type